# How to unset or disable hyperlinkctrl in wxpython only on some conditions

Tags: wxpython

I have created hyperlinkctrl on my panel.Under some conditions it should be hyperlink but other cases it should be just text not link.

How to do this?

```
self.Author = wx.HyperlinkCtrl(self, -1, "", "~")

if true:
   self.Author.SetLabel(str(self.aList['Author']))
   self.Author.SetURL("mailto:%s" % str(self.aList['Author']))
else:
   self.Author.SetLabel("N/A")
   self.Author.SetURL("N/A")
```

In the else case with `"N/A"` still it is linking.

can any one tell me how to unset the url in wxPython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply toggle between:

```
self.Author.Enable()
```

and:

```
self.Author.Disable()
```

Edit:
To redisplay `self.Author` without the underline which goes with a hyperlink

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, (-1, -1), wx.Size(300, 200))
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Author = wx.HyperlinkCtrl(self.panel1, -1, "", "http://127.0.0.1/some_directory/",pos=(30,50))
        self.Button = wx.Button(self.panel1, -1, "Click Me", pos=(80,100))
        self.Button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)
        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self,event):
        self.Author.Hide()
        if self.Author.IsEnabled():
            self.Author = wx.StaticText(self.panel1, -1, "http://127.0.0.1/some_directory/", pos=(30,50))
            self.Author.Disable()
        else:
            self.Author = wx.HyperlinkCtrl(self.panel1, -1, "", "http://127.0.0.1/some_directory/", pos=(30,50))
            self.Author.Enable()
        self.Author.Show()
        self.Update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'Hyperlink')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Also I dont want the hyperlink underline..can we remove that?

Comment: You could redefine self.Author as `StaticText`. If you are using sizers, I think that you would have to remove the panel from the sizer,define the panel again with self.Author as `StaticText` ,add the panel back into the sizer and then do a `self.Update()`, although that seems a little over the top, just to get rid of the underline

Comment: where I have to use the self.Update()?

Comment: Can you give me example pls?

Comment: Thanks Rolf..but you are told about sizers..still need to set those sizers ?and my sizers are in one seperate function

Comment: I tried your code ,but its not taking the redefined statictext().:-(  still it is in htperlink only